# Is a 12V 20amp switch too much for a pc?

Tags: voltage

So u got this switch for my pc and it is a 12V 20amp momentary switch will that damage the pc?

Comment: What are you using it for?  What will it be connected to?

Comment: a switch is just two conductors that touch when the switch is activated ... how would that damage the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a power, or reset, switch connected to the main board headers it will be fine.

The signals there are a few thousandths of an amp and 3 to 5 volts.

Excess volts or amps in a switch (when the switch is much stronger than the signal it switches) are just unused capacity, it is not any sort of hazard.